# Delete a node in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

(I know there are questions like this one but i didnt find a solution)

I have an XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfDay xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Day>
    <Caption>Mon 01</Caption>
    <Events>
      <Event>
        <Title>testTitle</Title>
        <Text>testText</Text>
        <Sound />
        <DateTime>2018-01-01T00:00:00</DateTime>
      </Event>
```

and i am trying to delete an "Event" node based on its title, there is my code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(File.ReadAllText(_eventsFile));
            XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Day/Events/Event[@Title="+txtTitle.Text+"]");
            if (node != null) { node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node); }
            doc.Save(_eventsFile);
            this.Close();
```

and no matter what i do it doesnt work, any thoughts?

The value of `txtTitle` is the `Title` of the `Event`, it gets the vaule automaticaly

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. Afterwards please [edit] the post and remove all unrelated code and make sure all necessary data is inline (i.e. `txtTitle.Text` can safely be replaced with inline constant). If you can't find answer after creating true minimal sample - feel free to read on "XML - nodes vs. attributes".

Answer (score 2):

2 errors in the path expression you are using:

- you need to use single quotes ' around the text you want to use as filter
- @ looks for an element having an attribute Title = the text, not for a subelement

try this:

```
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Day/Events/Event[Title='"+txtTitle.Text+"']");
```